# MacBook Air 11" (Late 2010) Touchpad/Trackpad doesn't work

Tags: 11.04, touchpad, macbook-air

Just upgraded my MacBook Air 3,1 (11" Late 2010) from Maverick to Natty Beta 1.

Trackpad stopped working. Any idea why this happened and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install `bcm5974-dkms` and `xf86-input-multitouch` from the mactel PPA.